# Saving session var with jquery doesn't seem to work

Tags: jquery, session

I'm having trouble storing session...

Code I'm using:

```
//save to session
    $.session("compareLeftContent","value");
    alert($.session("compareLeftContent"));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dWsKJ/ to play with.

Please any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On jsfiddle example you provided there is no session plugin attached. `$.session` is not included in jQuery. You need to use this plugin to have this functionality: [Jquery Session Plugin](https://github.com/AlexChittock/JQuery-Session-Plugin)

Then use `$.session.set` and `$.session.get` methods to store and read session keys.

example:

```
$.session.set("compareLeftContent","value");
alert($.session.get("compareLeftContent"));
```

Comment: if we have to store with cookies then

Answer (score 5):

Are you using session.js?

You need to set the session using `$.session.set`:

```
$.session.set("compareLeftContent", "value");
```

To retrieve the session value use `$.session.get`:

```
alert($.session.get("compareLeftContent"));
```

Comment: The other answer seemsed to be more complete with link to download page. I actually thought sessions was handled by jquery natively... stupid me, as I couldn't find anything in documentation... upvoted your answer anyways.