# CSS Change - save preferences made through JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, css

I'm making a website for someone who wants to make their font size changable. I change it with JQuery `$("body").css("font-size", "14px");`. But what is the best way to save this? Should I save it in a PHP Session (through AJAX) or is there a better way, like saving it in the browser cache?

Comment: either use web storage or cookie

Comment: Do you mean changeable globally or per user ?

Comment: One of solutions you can find here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14891615/saving-session-var-with-jquery-doesnt-seem-to-work

Comment: You have many options, localStorage, indexedDB, cookie, server-side's storage, each one has it's own usage and there is no _best way_, therefore voting to close as *primarily opinion-based*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that if the user need to be logged to see the page you can save this data into db and session together.

But you can save it on cookie (client-side) for a more large view, example if the user doesn't need to be logged.

Comment: I'll use a client-side cookie, since the user doesn't have to be logged in. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To save data just for a single user, use `localStorage` in modern browsers and `cookies` when it's not supported. You could use a small library like [Store.js](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js) to take care of this distinction.

If your website has a login, you should save this preference into the database, ideally via AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use html5 local storage or sessionStorage. Look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) for details about html5 storage

Answer (score 0):

If it's just simple pages for a small scale site, I'd just use ajax to save any font changes to a $_session['custom-font-size'] variable.  Then have a code block at the top of the page that adds your jquery if the variable isset()

```
if(isset($_session['custom-font-size']) == TRUE){
    x = '$("body").css("font-size", "14px");'
    // Or other jquery
}
```

If it's an MVC or account / database driven site I'd do something a bit different though.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

If its a user preference then I would not use cookies or HTML5 storage.  A user will want their settings remembered when they sign back in days/weeks later.  Cookies and HTML5 can be wiped out when the cookie expires, if the user clears their temp internet files, turn a browsers "private" settings on, etc...

I recommend adding a column to your DB for the setting, load that setting into a session variable as soon as the user signs in and then set the font using inline css or jQuery like this...

```
echo'<style>body {font-size: '.$_SESSION["userPrefFontSize"].'}</style>';
```

or

```
echo'<script>$("body").css("font-size", "'.$_SESSION["userPrefFontSize"].'");</script>';
```

Then if the users changes their setting do an ajax call that updates the DB and the session var.  When the ajax call comes back successfully then do a window refresh if you want to see the font change, or just do another $("body").css call to change the font.

Or abandon the ajax way of saving it and create an entire user preferences page in case they come back wanting to remember more setting.  User pref page -> contains many settings -> submits to itself -> update DB and session vars -> after updates finish relocate to see changes, `header( 'Location: userprefs.php' ); die();`

Answer (score -1):

You could also use [mediaqueries](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries) or [flowtype.js](http://simplefocus.com/flowtype/) to change your font-size.

Comment: I'm not the one who gave you this -1, but I'd like to mention that this kind of font size changing is not a screen size thing, but a user's preference. The website is targeted at an older audience, who may want to have a bigger font.