# JQuery Session Not Woring

Tags: javascript, jquery, session

I have a problem with jquery session. I have referenced the jquery session file as explained here [Saving session var with jquery doesn't seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14891615/saving-session-var-with-jquery-doesnt-seem-to-work) but still the session is not working.

Ami missing something. Kindly help.

```
  <script src="js/jquery.session.js"></script>
  $.session.set("login_token","ertyu");
  $.session.set("login_userame","fdghjkl");
```

Comment: What is not working? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
 <script src="js/jquery.session.js"></script>
 $.session("login_token","ertyu");
 $.session("login_userame","fdghjkl");
```